# Python regular expression grouping?

Tags: python, regex, grouping, email-validation

I've been trying to look for the code to match a regular expression on an email for a project. These are the requirements:

Email must be in the form of acct@domain

acct is 1 or more characters, and composed of only upper or lowercase alphabetic characters, numeric characters, dashes, periods, underscores and hyphens

acct cannot start or end with an underscore, dash, period or hyphen. There must be at least two letters before and after every period.

domain is 5 or more characters, and composed of only upper or lowercase alphabetic characters, numeric characters, dashes, periods, and hyphens, underscores

domain must have at least one period, and cannot start or end with an underscore, dash, period or hyphen. There must be at least two letters before and after every period.

I have figured out the acct part with the code:

```
if re.search("^[a-zA-z0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9-_]*$|^[a-zA-z0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9-_]+[\.]{1}[a-zA-z0-9]{2,}$", email):
    print "valid!"
```

Also the domain:

```
if re.search("^[a-zA-z0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9-_]+[\.]{1}[a-zA-z0-9]{2,}$", email):
    print "valid!"
```

**My problem is that i cannot figure out how to group them together and put an @ sign**

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if re.search("(^[a-zA-z0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9-_]*$|^[a-zA-z0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9-_]+[\.]{1}[a-zA-z0-9]{2,}$)@(^[a-zA-z0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9-_]+[\.]{1}[a-zA-z0-9]{2,}$)", email):<br>
    print "valid!
```

"

IT DOESN'T WORK! I can't get it to ever match. If you have suggestions that make the code less nooby please do let me know!

Comment: Where do these requirements come from?  They are wacky.  It is fairly common to have email addresses like `u.thant@un.example.org` simply because some people's name is a single letter.

Comment: Also the `{1}` quantifier is completely superfluous, and the backslash in a character class matches a literal backslash.  You want simply either `\.` or `[.]`.

Comment: You are only allowing a single period in either the account name or the domain part.  Your requirements imply that multiple periods are allowed, as long as there is more than one alphanumeric character between them.  This is slightly hard to combine -- you could use lookahead assertions to combine multiple overlapping constraints, but that complicates the regular expression significantly.  Given that the requirements seem to be pulled out of thin air anyway, I'm not sure it's worth the effort; but you can certainly find hundreds of examples of similar questions on this site to learn from.

Comment: You have a typo in all the character class `A-z` must be `A-Z`

Comment: @tripleee its a pretty simple beginners python class and the requirements are a little off but thanks for your insight!!

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Thanks! Typical me to make dumb typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to combine both the regexes.

```
if re.search(r"^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$", email):
    print "valid"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/48)

Regular Expression:

```
^                        the beginning of the string
(?:                      group, but do not capture:
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                           'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
  [a-zA-Z0-9-]*            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                           'Z', '0' to '9', '-' (0 or more times)
 |                        OR
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                           'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
  [a-zA-Z0-9-]+            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                           'Z', '0' to '9', '-' (1 or more times)
  [.]                      any character of: '.'
  [a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}          any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                           'Z', '0' to '9' (at least 2 times)
)                        end of grouping
@                        '@'
[a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                         '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+           any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                         '0' to '9', '-', '_' (1 or more times)
[.]                      any character of: '.'
[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}          any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                         '0' to '9' (at least 2 times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the anchors from the two groups and apply it to the whole group as

```
if re.search(r"^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-\w]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$", email):
    print "valid!"
```

**Changes made**

- The anchors `^` and `$` are applied to the entire regex
- `[\.]{1}` can be simplified as `\.` since it matches only **one** occurence of `.`
- `[a-zA-z0-9-_]` can be simplified as `[-\w]`

Comment: @Jay `r` makes the string raw string, which will handle the back slashes in the regex

Answer (score 1):

Below is the regex which can validate all your criteria and I hope it is also more efficient.

```
^(?![\W_])((?:([\w-]{2,})\.?){1,})(?<![\W_])@(?![\W_])(?=[\w.-]{5,})(?=.+\..+)((?:([\w-]{2,})\.?){1,})(?<![\W_])$
```

And here is the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aR4hJ0/10).